# I get wrong date format when using a batch script to convert from excel to csv

Tags: excel, batch-file, jscript

I have an excel file with UK dates, when I run the below script to convert the file to csv the date format changes to US format. How do I fix it?
Can anyone advise on a batch script to use instead of Jscript?

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;

var xlCSV = 6;


var objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ARGS.Item(0));
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
objExcel.Visible = false;

var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(ARGS.Item(1));
objWorksheet.SaveAs( ARGS.Item(2), xlCSV);


objExcel.Quit();
```

Update: I've also tried this vbs script but the date format still changes from UK to US.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: The code you are using to convert the file is `JSCRIPT`.  The only thing the batch portion does is execute the JSCRIPT. There is no point in even having the batch file section.  You could just have the whole script as jscript.

Comment: I agree with Squashman, ths issue is Excel (locale) related and also the jscript code for the COM object; least batch-file.

Comment: Yep. I am with them ^

Comment: Can you advise on a different solution to convert excel to csv?